# Locating an app by its bundle identifier from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, spotlight

I am looking for a way to find an app's location on the system from the command line using its bundle identifier. I can open it like this:

```
open -b 'com.zerotier.ZeroTierOne'
```

... where com.zerotier.ZeroTierOne is my bundle ID, but what I want to do is locate where the app is actually installed. I want a command that will return (for example):

```
/Applications/ZeroTier One.app
```

in response to a query by identifier 'com.zerotier.ZeroTierOne'.

The "-R" option to open will reveal in finder but I want this to be completely non-interactive and done via a shell script.

Answer (score 23):

The magic command is:

```
mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = "com.zerotier.ZeroTierOne"
```

You can determine this by working backwards from `mdls foo | grep kMDItemCF`

So if you didn't know iPhoto's CF Bundle Identifier:

```
Mac:~ me$ mdls /Applications/iPhoto.app | grep kMDItemCF
kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier           = "com.apple.iPhoto"
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent API in Foundation for this?

Comment: @mservidio [I have answered that question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173020/3939277) because it is programming-specific

Comment: @AdamIerymenko (thanks for ZeroTier btw!) You don't need the extra pipe to grep: `mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -raw "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"` works.

Comment: Which one applications is default by `open` command with `-b bundleId`?