# How to handle bundle identifiers with spaces?

Tags: macos, applications, tor

Lets assume my current directory is `/Applications` and it contains all my apps. Lets say I want to know the bundle identifier for [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/):

```
$ mdls -raw -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier 'Google Chrome.app'
com.google.Chrome
```

Now let’s use that to [locate the app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115948/26865):

```
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = com.google.Chrome
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
```

Now lets try the same for [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). First, get the bundle identifier:

```
$ mdls -raw -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier TorBrowser.app
org.mozilla.tor browser
```

Then, locate the app:

```
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = org.mozilla.tor browser
```

Nothing. I likely need to quote it:

```
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = 'org.mozilla.tor browser'
```

Nope, still nothing. Lets try something else:

```
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = 'org.mozilla.tor'
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = "org.mozilla.tor browser"
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = org.mozilla.tor\ browser
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = "org.mozilla.tor\ browser"
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = 'org.mozilla.tor%20browser'
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = 'org.mozilla.tor+browser'
$ mdfind kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier = 'org.mozilla.tor_browser'
```

Nothing works. This is the only app I ever had this issue with, and the only one I ever saw with a space in its bundle identifier. How can we reference it?

Comment: I can't check it, because I do not have an app with space in bundle identifier, but how about escaping the space with `\\`` ? Or `"` quotes?

Comment: Nope. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A proper bundle identifier should **not** have a space in it. According to Apple's [App Distribution Guide -> About Bundle IDs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW8), a

> "...bundle ID string must be a [uniform type identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/UniformTypeIdentifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH60) (UTI) that contains
>   only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period
>   (.). The string should be in reverse-DNS format. For example, if your
>   organization’s domain is `Acme.com` and you create an app named `Hello`,
>   you could assign the string `com.Acme.Hello` as your app’s bundle ID.

So, technically, `org.mozilla.tor browser` is not a valid bundle identifier, so you'll get unexpected results when trying to work with it. It should likely be changed (by the developer) to something like `org.mozilla.tor.browser` or `org.mozilla.tor-browser`, etc.